# Can I link two object types in Foundry without using either objects primary key?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I have two object types in Foundry.

- Object A
- Object B

Both objects have property Y but property Y is not the primary key of either of these objects.

Is it possible to create a link between these two objects without creating a transitive object?

Answer (score 2):

Semantically links in the ontology represent explicitly stating that two objects are related, so the links must identify pairs by their primary key values.

Like you say you can create a transitive object or create a mapping table dataset and a many-to-many link type.